# Opencart: How to disable seo for particular pages?

Tags: php, seo, opencart, shopping-cart

I'm using opencart version 1.5.5.1 for our website. SEO url is enabled in the site. For a certain requirement we modified header,footer,product files for some category/product pages. So we created new controller and template files like: categorynew.php, categorynew.tpl, productnew.php etc.

The issue is that once the seo is enabled both http://domain.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=59_72&product_id=63 and http://domain.com/index.php?route=product/productnew&path=59_72&product_id=63 becomes http://domain.com/products/categoryname?product_id=63.

Is it possible to disable seo in my new pages by adding some code in my controller files?

Please help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: While technically Robin's method seems to be working, I'm not sure it's working as you want. Are you trying to disable SEO URL's completely on those pages, or just stop the new controller routes from generating product/category URL's for their rewrites? You should notice with Robin's answer you will disable EVERY SEO URL on the new pages, not just the product/category URL's for those controllers

Comment: As the new pages are used in iframes disabling seo for the whole page will not be a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's difficult to give an absolute answer as you don't mention where your these URLs are generated. I have no possibility to test it locally so you have to take this with a grain of salt.

Looking at the code in **catalog/controller/common/seo_url.php** (line 60):

```
if ($this->config->get('config_seo_url')) {
```

If you wanted to disable SEO for all URL:s generated within the route product/productnew you would do something like this:

```
if ($this->config->get('config_seo_url') &&
   !strpos($this->request->get['route'], 'product/productnew') === 0) {
```

Simply edit:

```
!strpos($this->request->get['route'], 'product/productnew')
```

to the route you want to disable SEO for.

I hope this helps.